# Can i give users points for rewarded videos

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

Is it against google's policy to give users who watch rewarded videos, give them points that are convertible for real rewards .
For example , Top 3 users will receive real gifts, the ranking is based on points that are gathered by answering quiz questions  and from watching rewarded ads

Answer (score 2):

Its against policy to convert them into real rewards. Refer below link for allowed/disallowed policies

Reference - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en

> Rewarded ads must not be placed in user flows that offer monetary
> compensation or other incentives that can be converted into monetary
> compensation (including gift cards, discounts for physical goods or
> services, and cryptocurrencies).